# Apache sqoop errors

Tags: oracle, hadoop, sqoop

I want to connect to RDBMS with sqoop. My RDBMS is Oracle. In final state I faced below errors:

> 16/04/24 06:11:13 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 100%
>   16/04/24 06:11:13 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1461141375226_0002 failed with state FAILED due to: 
>   16/04/24 06:11:13 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: The MapReduce job has already been retired. Performance
>   16/04/24 06:11:13 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: counters are unavailable. To get this information, 
>   16/04/24 06:11:13 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: you will need to enable the completed job store on 
>   16/04/24 06:11:13 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: the jobtracker with:
>   16/04/24 06:11:13 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: mapreduce.jobtracker.persist.jobstatus.active = true
>   16/04/24 06:11:13 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: mapreduce.jobtracker.persist.jobstatus.hours = 1
>   16/04/24 06:11:13 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: A jobtracker restart is required for these settings
>   16/04/24 06:11:13 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: to take effect.
>   16/04/24 06:11:13 DEBUG util.ClassLoaderStack: Restoring classloader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@2f686d1f
>   16/04/24 06:11:13 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Error during import: Import job failed!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using HDFS directory as target. May be a permission issue with the target-dir. Try changing the target directory to some location where you have full access.

For better understanding please post the command that you used to execute sqoop.